# Testing with jasmine with angular and unobtrusive jquery validate

Tags: unit-testing, jquery-validate, jasmine, unobtrusive-validation

I am using angular js with jquery unobtrusive validation for mvc application .
I am writing unit tests for my angular code and i have been using jasmine and sinon for mocking my services .

Everything is working fine but i dont have any idea on how i can mock and test situation where in i have some form like ....  and i am doing if($("#someForm").valid()){...///do something}

this directly goes in jquery validate function but this.form[0] is undefined error is thrown.

I also tried spyon($,"valid").fakecall(fn ) from jasmine but get error $ has not valid method

Comment: spyon($.fn,"valid").fakecall(fn );